# get_serving_url usage in template? (=gae issue 3688)

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I use the function get_serving_url to display an image referenced by an entity in a template? The situation is something like this and won't work:

```
{{ a.matched_images.get().get_serving_url() }}
```

Can you please help me how to achieve a thumbnail image with get_serving_url in a template?

This issue is [acknowledged](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3688)

Thanks

Comment: Do you still require an answer to this question? If not, please provide your own answer or close / delete the question.

Comment: Thanks we solved it with help in the GAE google group

Comment: We in SO would appreciate it if you told us how it was solved or even a link to the relevant discussion in the google group.

Comment: We added a function to the model i.e. '    def uri2view(self):#enable get_serving_url
        return images.get_serving_url(str(self.matched_images.get().primary_image.key()))+'=s100''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the URLs and zip them up with your images in a list before passing them into Django - you really shouldn't be calling API methods from inside your templates anyway. Alternately, create a method on your datastore model that does this, and pass in the entity or entities holding the blobs.

Comment: Thank you Nick the problem was solved and the view now works as required.

Answer (score 1):

[Nicklas R's thread in in the GAE Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/8b0295c92a2679ec?fwc=2) explains how he actually solved it:

> It works like proposed like this in template:
>
> ```
> <img src="{{ ad.uri2view }}">
> ```
>
> With backend function added to model:
>
> ```
> def uri2view(self):#enable get_serving_url 
>     return images.get_serving_url(str(self.matched_images.get().primary_image.key()))+'=s120'
> ```

Comment: Yes something like that seemed to work for me. You may how a look since it's the way thumbnails display if you look at my site http://www.koolbusiness.com/li where previously images were stored in several sizes, we now only need to store one object per image and then get_serving_url can make the thumbnail for us!